# Is addEventListener ignored after long hidden duration?

Tags: javascript, html

My mobile web page is using following JavaScript to show current server time.
If I show this page, then browse another tab for several minutes and back to the page, it works well.
(i.e. the time of second visit is displayed)

```
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
        if (!document.hidden) {
            // show current server time
        }
    });
```

However if I show this page, then browse another tab and leave my phone during business hour,
displayed time is the first one when I browse the page after business hour.

- Is addEventListener cleared after long inactivity?
- Does page visibility event fire properly after long inactivity?
- If not, how can I achieve the same behavior?

I use Chrome 39 on Android 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal behaviour, any pending **JavaScript** execution will not be performed when the tab loses the focus or the browser is inactive, what you can do is attach to `window.onfocus` to update the server hour in the page:

```
window.onfocus = function(){
  //do here what you need.
};
```

You can see the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onfocus).

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I'll give it a try.